# pandas dataframe interpolate

Tags: pandas, dataframe

So I see that there is a way to interpolate for a pandas series object http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html. Is there an equivalent method for dataframes? I'd like to interpolate every column.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html#pandas.DataFrame.interpolate This was added in 0.13, which is slated to be released soon. You can wait for that or install from source for try something like `df.apply(lambda x: x.interploate(), axis=1)`.

Comment: Does this apply it to the columns or rows? I tried df=df.apply(lambda col: col.interpolate('linear'), axis=1), yet it's still not interpolating all the columns.

Comment: You may not need the `axis=1` argument. I always forget whether that's row-wise or column-wise.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried it in pandas 0.13, and it works:

```
a = Series([0,nan,1,2])
b = DataFrame([a,a,a,a])

b
     0    1  2   3
0    0  NaN  1   2
1    0  NaN  1   2
2    0  NaN  1   2
3    0  NaN  1   2


b.interpolate(axis=1)

     0     1     2   3
0    0   0.5     1   2
1    0   0.5     1   2
2    0   0.5     1   2
3    0   0.5     1   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally different columns in a pandas DataFrame contain different type of information, so an interpolation method may not apply or you may need different methods depending on the data.

Supose a DataFrame called data, with columns 'TimeStamp', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'Value'. You can interpolate NaN values of each column by doing:

```
data.TimeStamp = data.TimeStamp.interpolate(method = 'time')
data.Lat = data.Lat.interpolate(method = 'spline')
data.Long = data.Long.interpolate(method = 'spline')
data.Value = data.Value.interpolate(method = 'linear')
```

If the data in all your columns are homogeneous, I suppose you can call the same method for all of them.

More information about the interpolate function:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html

Comment: UPADTE: When interpolating via a polynomial or spline approximation, you must also specify the degree or order of the approximation: df.interpolate(method='spline', order=2)

Answer (score 0):

Building of off MonkeyButters helpful answer, if you want to just interpolate one column this works. Albeit a little indirectly:

```
#create a dataframe with some missing values
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({    
    'a':[1,2,np.nan,4,np.nan,6,np.nan,7,8],
    'b':np.random.randn(9)    
    })
```

Yields:

```
a   b
0   1.0 -1.085631
1   2.0 0.997345
2   NaN 0.282978
3   4.0 -1.506295
4   NaN -0.578600
5   6.0 1.651437
6   NaN -2.426679
7   7.0 -0.428913
8   8.0 1.265936
```

Create a series and then write back to the DataFrame:

```
se = df['a'].interpolate()
df['a'] = se.values

a   b
0   1.0 -1.085631
1   2.0 0.997345
2   3.0 0.282978
3   4.0 -1.506295
4   5.0 -0.578600
5   6.0 1.651437
6   6.5 -2.426679
7   7.0 -0.428913
8   8.0 1.265936
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent method for dataframes? I'd like to interpolate every column.

As a general tip, when a series method is missing for DataFrame, you can always use `DataFrame.apply()` with the series method. As `DataFrame.apply()` iterates over columns by defaut (`axis=`index`).

```
df = df.apply(pd.Series.interpolate)
```

Of course, here DataFrame.interpolate() is now available.

---

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Build some dataframe with NaN
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4))
df = df.transform(np.sort)
na_mask = np.random.randint(2, size=df.shape)
df[1:-1] = df[1:-1].where(na_mask[1:-1]==0, np.NaN)
df.plot()

# Interpolate all columns using the Series method
df = df.apply(pd.Series.interpolate)
df.plot()
```